# How to retrieve several columns from table b

Tags: sql

I have the table A

```
conipk    contittle concycle  ttlid

122786  108405  S13 107552    
122787  108405  S13 107552    
122788  108405  S13 107552    
122789  108405  S13 107552
```

Table b

```
conipk    contype    concile   conamt
122786    LU     N         5.000
122786    LU         N         7.000
122787    LU     N         1.000
122788    LU     N         3.000
122788    LU         N         1.000
122789    LU     N         1.000
```

I want the 3 columns and the first record from table B.

The result desired is

```
conipk    contittle concycle  ttlid   contype concile conanmt

122786  108405    S13       107552    LU     N    5
122787  108405    S13       107552    LU     N    1
122788  108405    S13       107552    LU     N    3
122789  108405    S13       107552    LU     N    1
```

I did the query

```
SELECT      
   rc.contype, rc.concile, rc.conamtt, c.conipk, c.concycle, c.ttlid
FROM
   Contract c  
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT TOP 1 
        r.conipk, r.contype, r.concile, r.conamt 
    FROM
        rules r 
    JOIN  
        contract c2 ON r.conipk = c2.conipk) AS rc ON rc.conipk = c.conipk
```

But I just get the first record.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you define "first" in table B?

Comment: Have you tried join instead of left join?

Comment: What DB server and version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're only joining to one record from B, not one record *per key*.

Since you don't state which server software you're using it's hard to come up with a definitive answer, but this will work in SQL Server 2005 and Later (provided you provide the correct order to determine the "first" record):

```
SELECT      
    rc.contype, 
    rc.concile,
    rc.conamtt,
    c.conipk,
    c.concycle,
    c.ttlid
FROM contract c  
LEFT JOIN  ( 
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.conipk ORDER BY ???) RowNUm,
        r.conipk,
        r.contype,
        r.concile,
        r.conamt 
        from rules r 
        join contract c2 on r.conipk = c2.conipk ) AS rc  
    on  c.conipk = rc.conipk
        AND rc.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: D. Stanley Thank you so much. I am using SQL SERVER 2008. It worked.